# Minifying Bootstrap css with BundleConfig

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4, asp.net-mvc-5, minify

I am working with ASP.NET MVC Framework 5 with BundleConfig, which allows me to bundle and minify my `.js` and `.css` files. Suddenly, I have realized that it can't minify Bootstrap `.css` files due to variables in it (version 4.3.1). I always see such errors:

```
/* Minification failed. Returning unminified contents.
(1,39): run-time error CSS1062: Expected semicolon or closing curly-brace, found '-'
(1,56): run-time error CSS1062: Expected semicolon or closing curly-brace, found '-'
```

I have tried using SCSS minified files and pure CSS provided by Bootstrap, but in all cases result is the same. SCSS files can be minified by web compiler, but BundleConfig is still trying to compress them by itself and fails. Even with the single file.

```
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap.min.css"));
    }
```

In addition, I have used different minifiers and found out that they give different results for the same file and it is hard to understand which is better.

But even if I would use any external tool, I need advice on what should I do with my BundleConfig not to show these errors.

Comment: Seems like I saw a very similar question not long ago, and I wasn't able to reproduce - I have an MVC5 project that includes Bootstrap 4 in a bundle, and it works just fine. What version of Visual Studio and System.Web.Optimization are you using?

Comment: I've seen issues with bundling "already minified" files such as "bootstrap.min.css".  I never could nail down the problem, but try putting the unminified version in your bundle instead, and letting the bundling mechanism do the minifying work.  Right now it appears you're essentially minifying bootstrap twice.

Comment: It works with Bootstrap 3 which is used in MVC template by default but after update to latest version it doesn't work well neither pure css or min.css. 
Visual Studio 2019 (latest)
System.Web.Optimization 1.1

Comment: Seems to be related to the use of CSS variables in the latest version of Bootstrap and the fact that the bundle/minify doesn't deal with them correctly: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/51ba77f7-ec13-483b-98c8-65cb1735db7e/vs-minify-css-gives-error-css1062-expected-semicolon-or-closing-curlybrace-found-?forum=visualstudiogeneral or https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/3023. I am facing the same issue in VS2019.

Comment: I was trying to achieve the same thing, but failed. Looks like there is something in CSS that is not properly parsing to minified version.